# Is returning a Span<byte> from a temporary byte[] dangerous (will generate an exception possibly on usage)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

In a .NET Core 3.0 project, I have an interface that return a `Span<byte>`. This works for a large set of classes except one particular implementation which can generate its data on the fly (due to not caching it).

The implementation looks like:

```
public Span<byte> Data => CompileBytes();
```

where it would be something like (this is abstract code but pretty close to a use case)

```
public byte[] CompileBytes()
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        foreach (IDataSource data in DataSources)
            stream.Write(data.ByteArray);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I have been looking around online to see if there's a guarantee that this is safe to do but haven't found any.

My worry is that `Span` is a very thin layer around the data that the GC will ignore such that the GC assumes we will not let the span outlive the underlying buffer, and the temporary byte array that is created will eventually get GC'd, which means I could potentially have a ticking time bomb on my hands if it for some reason does a GC while someone other code is using the span. Is this the case? Can I return a `Span<>` for a temporary object and be perfectly okay (under the assumption it is properly used by staying in the bounds of the span)?

The definition seems to be implementation dependent so I can't figure out with my limited knowledge if it holds onto the reference or not... because if so, then I am safe and my question is answered.

The MSDN says 'memory safe' but I am unsure the exact specifics by which they define memory safe and if it covers my definition. As such, if it does, then this question is answered.

I am not using any `unsafe` code.

Comment: `public Span<byte> Data => CompileBytes();` in which context is this? Can you provide a full, compilable example? It looks like a property somewhere and I doubt a Span property is allowed.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Added an implementation example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a reference to a managed array in a `Span<T>` is safe, even if it is the only reference to it.
As described in the article [All About Span: Exploring a New .NET Mainstay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx), `Span<T>` uses a special way of storing these references, a `ByReference<T>`, which is implemented as a JIT intrinsic.

Quoting the linked article (section **How Is `Span<T>` Implemented?**):

> `Span<T>` is actually written to use a special internal type in the runtime that’s treated as a just-in-time (JIT) intrinsic, with the JIT generating for it the equivalent of a ref T field

And section **What Is `Memory<T>` and Why Do You Need It?**

> `Span<T>` is a ref-like type as it contains a ref field, and ref fields can refer not only to the beginning of objects like arrays, but also to the middle of them [...] These references are called interior pointers, and tracking them is a relatively expensive operation for the .NET runtime’s garbage collector.

The last part of that quote clarifies that the reference stored in `Span<T>` is indeed tracked by the GC, so it will not clean up memory that is still being referenced